# List children pages, unless none exist, in which case, list sibling pages, in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a navigation structure like this:

- Home
- About

  - The Team
  - Our Mission
- Locations

  - Chicago
  - New York
  - Los Angeles
- Services
- Contact Us

If I'm looking at the About page, I want the sidebar to display:

- The Team
- Our Mission

If I'm looking at the Services page, I want the sidebar to display:

- Home
- About
- Locations
- Services
- Contact Us

This is the code I'm currently using. How can I modify it so that it works the way I want?

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
        $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
    } else {
        $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
    }
    $children = get_pages('child_of='.$parent);
    if( count( $children ) > 0 ) {
?>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_pages ("&title_li=&child_of=$parent"); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should either do it outright or at least show you how:

> when viewing a Page that has children (or is a child) it displays only children of that parent.
>
> - When visiting main page, all top level pages are listed in the sidebar.
> - When visiting a top level page with no children, all top level pages are listed.
> - When visiting a top level page with children, just the children pages, and descendant pages, are listed.
> - When visiting a child page, just the children, and descendant pages, of that parent, are listed.

```
<?php
$output = wp_list_pages('echo=0&depth=1&title_li=<h2>Top Level Pages </h2>' );
if (is_page( )) {
  $page = $post->ID;
  if ($post->post_parent) {
    $page = $post->post_parent;
  }
  $children=wp_list_pages( 'echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li=' );
  if ($children) {
    $output = wp_list_pages ('echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li=<h2>Child Pages</h2>');
  }
}
echo $output;
?>
```

from: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_subpages_even_if_on_a_subpage

This method takes advantage of the `echo=0` parameter, which returns the results as a string to a variable. The `if ($children)` test now works because `wp_list_pages()` will return empty if it finds no matches.